# koGrid totalServerItems

Tags: knockout.js, kogrid

I am having problems with this value in my grid.

It looks like it is not taking the observable I pass to the grid config with the total Items.

I've got three koGrids in three different tabs. All of them using the same initialization:

```
data-bind="koGrid: {data: records,
                                         autogenerateColumns: false,
                                         isMultiSelect: false,
                                         displayRowIndex: false,
                                         displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
                                         enablePaging: true,
                                         pageSizes: pageSizes,
                                         pageSize: pageSize,
                                         totalServerItems: totalItems,
                                        footerTemplate: 'koGridDebugFooter',
                                         currentPage: currentPage,                                        
                                         columnDefs:[
                                            {field: 'Created', width:300},
                                            {field:'Name', width:300},
                                            {field: 'Value', width:300}                                            
                                         ]} ">
```

I have 12 rows in the server, when I specify a page size of 10 the total server items remains at 10 and, therefore, the navigation buttons remain disabled.

If I add a label with the value of my view model, i.e. viewmodel.totalServerItems, the value it contains is the right one (12), however the footer is showing one different (10).

I'have modified these lines in the definition of the kogrid:

```
/***********************************************
* FILE: ..\Src\GridClasses\Footer.js
***********************************************/
kg.Footer = function (grid) {
    var self = this;

    this.maxRows;

    //if (grid.config.totalServerItems() !== null && grid.config.totalServerItems() !== undefined) {
        this.maxRows = grid.config.totalServerItems; //observable
    //} else {
    //    this.maxRows = grid.maxRows; //observable
    //}
```

So that now I am always setting the observable to this parameter. 
The only risk I see is when the caller is not setting the parameter. But I am always doing it.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you know another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

the totalServerItems is inside paging octions like this:

```
self.PagingOptions = {
            pageSizes: ko.observableArray([10, 20, 50]),
            pageSize: ko.observable(10),
            totalServerItems: ko.observable(0),
            currentPage: ko.observable(1)
        };
```